# How do these exponents simplify

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Might someone explain How does  $∣{2^C}∣∣{B^A} ∣ =({2^n})^{(n^n)} ={2^n}^{n^n} ={2^{n^n+1}}$ I'm interested in the exponent's here - how does the final product simplify to make sense: ${2^{n^n+1}}$?

Note that $|A|=|B|=|C|=n$
Thanks so much

Comment: It should be $2^{n^{n+1}}$. And I’m only referring to the last equation.  I haven’t looked at your A, B, or C.

Comment: You either have typos with your typesetting or you misread what the statement was.  Recognize that $a^b+c$ is different than $a^{b+c}$.

Comment: As for why $n\cdot n^n = n^{n+1}$ this is just application of the fact that $n=n^1$ and that $x^a\cdot x^b = x^{a+b}$ for positive $x$.  Here, $\color{red}{n}^{\color{blue}{1}}\cdot \color{red}{n}^{\color{blue}{n}} = \color{red}{n}^{\color{blue}{1}+\color{blue}{n}}$

Answer (score 0):

$∣{2^C}∣∣{B^A} ∣ =({2^n}) * (n^n) $